# Get string from URL

Tags: php, string, url

I had a little issue, i need to extract a string from the URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/category/firstcat/second-cat/
```

All my URLs has this structure, and I need to catch the "firstcat" string

I would appreciate your help!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do this on the current url the user is on, you'll need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. That will show you the current uri open, in this case `/category/firstcat/second-cat/`.

Then use anything you prefer to parse the string and get to the element you want, for example:

```
$elms = explode('/', $uri) ;
$firstcat = $elms[2] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you using mod_rewrite? Place a rule in your htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/ ?cat=$1&subcat=$2&name=$3
```

And you'll have it ready in $_GET array.